Easy way to Verify Ubuntu ISO?
Is there an easy way to verify the Ubuntu ISO?  The tutorial here from canonical seems very difficult just to verify an iso of ubuntu 24.04

That is the easy way ...

Actually it is not.  I asked the question so that I could answer it myself to help others.  I've got just a few lines, and the tutorial has you installing gpg keys.  It is totally not necessary and totally blind to regular users.

Does this answer your question? Is there an alternative for the Windows software "hashcheck" in Ubuntu?

Go to the releases page
https://releases.ubuntu.com/
Below is 24.04
https://releases.ubuntu.com/noble/
Click on the Sha256Sums link and right click and "save as"
SHA256SUMS.txt  (it will choose the name automatically)
Make sure the iso and the checksum are in the same directory.

Then type this
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS.txt --ignore-missing

You will get an OK message and a warning.
:~/Downloads$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS.txt --ignore-missing
ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 line is improperly formatted

I hope this helps.  The tutorial on the website is far more complex than it really needs to be.  That is the problem with linux.
Someone asked.. "What is the use if the sha256 is not valid?"
I think the ancient old instructions were before https was enforced with all browsers.  Here is a screenshot below:

You can also use the usb image writer's verification by pasting url


What is the point of verification if you're skipping verifying that the hashes themselves are valid?

Well the clicking of the hash will be a https which will be certified.  Then you right click and save.

Then the ISO download would also be via HTTPS, no? A simple look at the browser download status should tell you whether the file downloaded ok

Yes.. perhaps.. but I downloaded a torrent since I assumed the directly link would be busy.  But people might also download from mirrors.  I also noticed that the usb image writer on linux mint has a verification gui.  I will probably add to this post, but I'm not sure if ubuntu has it, so I need to get the app name.

If the torrent metadata was obtained from an official source, then that has even less need of verification - the torrent mechanism has verification of individual blocks of data as a core component.

Well then .. what is the purpose of verification then?

After verifying the ISO is good and using it to create a bootable thumb drive, you can double check everything went ok by removing the thumb drive, plugging it back in, and running these two commands:
cd /media/YourUserName/'Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64'/
md5sum -c md5sum.txt | less
The first command CDs you to the thumb drive and the second uses the md5sum file on the thumb drive to verify that all the files are intact and readable.
